# Uploading a file in protractor on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, file-upload, protractor

I would like to upload a picture and it's working in local but failing on jenkins with the following code:

```
const fileToUpload = await '../../files/test-automation-660x330.png';
const absolutePath = await path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);

await this.uploadButton.sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

I get the this error message:

```
WebDriverError: invalid argument: File not found : /opt/jenkins_root/workspace/project-name-e2e/e2e/files/test-automation-660x330.png
```

Comment: Can you double check the path? Does `files` directory exist?

Comment: Yes it is, because it's working in local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a problem with file detecting remotely (while on jenkins). You probably have to set up the file detection with the protractor browser.

I suggest you take a look at [Remote File Upload Protractor test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215697/remote-file-upload-protractor-test)

Comment: Many thanks. Refreshing typescipt and addig these 2 lines solved the problem:  
    `import * as remote from 'selenium-webdriver/remote';`
    `browser.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector());`

Answer (score 0):

did you try double quotes in your path e.g "../../yourimg.png" ?
I think that you need to include in "" your path .

Comment: like  const fileToUpload = await '"../../files/test-automation-660x330.png"';?

Comment: That's not working. :\  This way the two path will be linked, but not with the upper folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
const path = require('path');
const fileToUpload = path.resolve('./e2e/files-to-upload/testFile1.txt');
const fileButton= element(by.css('input[data-id=addDownloadableFileButton]'));

await addDownloadableFileButton.s`enter code here`endKeys(fileToUpload);
```

I have something like this in my project and it works fine. We're using Bamboo instead of Jenkins

Comment: I tried it, but i get the same error. Maybe the problem is near the jenkins.